# Setting a correct package name for a .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers

After reading the documentation for Google's Protocol Buffers I wished to implement them in my client, so far I have the following:

```
package com.christopher.kade;
option java_package= "protocol";

message Protocol {
    required string keyword = 1;
    optional string value = 2;
    optional string type = 3;
}
```

But when generated, the file has as a package "protocol" and therefore `IntellIJ` gives me the following error:

> Package name 'protocol' does not correspond to the file path 'com.christopher.kade.protocol'

Please note that if I take away the option, the plugin creates a **new** package called `com.christopher.kade`.

What should I add to my `.proto` file in order to have the right package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the same full package name in package and java_package to make it work:

```
package com.christopher.kade.protocol;
option java_package= "com.christopher.kade.protocol";
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, just drop the java_package and use package.
The java binding will default to the proto package if java_package is not specified.

```
package com.christopher.kade.protocol;

message Protocol {
    required string keyword = 1;
    optional string value = 2;
    optional string type = 3;
}
```

The main use for java_package is to generate the java code in a different package to the proto package.  Perhaps your proto package naming conventions do not follow the java conventions, or perhaps you have changed your java package following a corporate rebrand, but you dont want to change the package on the wire which would break compatibility.

For instance you could make the proto package `com.christopher.kade`, and this is what you would use in any other api clients, while generating the java code into `com.christopher.kade.protocol` with this:

```
package com.christopher.kade;
option java_package= "com.christopher.kade.protocol";

message Protocol {
    required string keyword = 1;
    optional string value = 2;
    optional string type = 3;
}
```